# Why "for( i = 0.1 ; i != 1.0 ; i += 0.1)" doesn't break at i = 1.0?

Tags: c, floating-point

I had an exam today in C and I was asked a question similar to:

> What is wrong with this program:
>
> ```
> for( x = .1 ; x != 1.0 ; x += .1)
>     printf("%f\n", x);
> ```

I couldn't solve it and since I had to write something I marked `.1` as an error. But, when I went back home, I run this program, It turned out that it doesn't break when `x` equals to `1.0` and stuck in an infinite loop:

```
$ cat exam.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    float x;

    for(x = .1 ; x != 1.0 ; x += .1)
        printf("%f\n", x);

    return 0;
}
$ gcc exam.c -o exam
$ ./exam
0.100000
0.200000
0.300000
0.400000
0.500000
0.600000
0.700000
0.800000
0.900000
1.000000 <- ?
1.100000
1.200000
1.300000
1.400000
1.500000
....
```

Could someone please explain why this is happening.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Welcome to the awesome world of floating-point math.

Comment: 1.00000 may actually be something like 1.000000001. The nature of floating points.

Comment: Besides that, you should never terminate an incrementing for loop with a test for equality -- always "equal or greater" or some such.

Comment: @BoPersson: while in *this* case the answer *may* be the same, redirecting a C question to a Python one is IMHO a mistake - especially considering the fact that Python does not use fixed FP types, such as the ones defined in IEEE-754, contrary to most C implementations.

Comment: @Als: I find that [floating-point-gui.de](http://floating-point-gui.de) is a much better link to point newbies to.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a typical question for homework.

The Problem is that the 0.1 cannot be exactly stored in a float better check for <= 1.0

However **this just works only for a very limited range** like Cthulhu said. I missed that problem completely. Of cause **it is better to use `int` and divide its value later**.

Comment: +1. I did not know about this trick, but I've always used <= for everything.

Comment: @Cthulhu you are right, I added a line pointing to your answer. For this special question my solution would work, but of cause not until that 500 example. You got a +1 from me too.

Answer (score 18):

### <= or < is not the solution!

Using of floating points in the loop is **not** without issues.
The rounding error accumulates. Even with `<=`, the loop **might not run** the right number of times.

It works for `<=1.0` **[(10 times)](http://ideone.com/KJtaEB)**, but runs one time less than expected for `<=50.0` **[(499 times)](http://ideone.com/ouWiqC)**.

```
 for(i = 0.1 ; i <= 50.0 ; i += 0.1)
       { ... }//runs 499 times, not 500!
```

This is an issue that might not be very easy to discover, if you do run into it.
Rounding it before comparison (**[rounding functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Rounding-Functions.html)**) might help, but the only sure-shot solution is to...

**Use integers as control variables in loops.**

Comment: +1 to pointing out the real problem

Answer (score 3):

never use `!=` in the `for` loop, it leads to a very difficult to find errors when your loop variable never reaches the value you expect. always use `<` instead.

Answer (score 2):

It is due to IEEE floating point standard. [Check Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)

```
0.1 + 0.2 = 0.3 => FALSE - Expected: 0.3 | Real: 0.30000000000000004
```

Check out real (JavaScript) demo here: http://k8.no-ip.org/stackoverflow/13542220.htm

Answer (score 1):

0.1 cannot be stored exactly in a float. Floating point numbers contain an approximate value and you are trying to equalize it to an exact value.

Comment: @rekire: And so have hundreds of answers to the dozens of duplicates for this Q, so whats your point?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion, every time you need loops use **integers**.

```
int x;
float y = 0;
for( x = 1; x < 11; x += 1){
    y += 0.1; 
    printf("%f\n", y);
}
```

Alternatively you can use this too:

```
for( x = 1; x < 11; x += 1){
    printf("%f\n", ( x / 10.0 ) );
}
```

In both cases you keep the loops values as integers.

Comment: `x != 10` is BAD. really really BAD.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `x < 10`? The answer's code has `!= 10` as condition, that sounds like `< 10`.

Comment: @effeffe Nope because he wants the 1.0 printed I think.

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto well, he initially puts the `x != 1.0` condition in the loop, I don't think he want to se it printed.