# Instead of printing 100 it prints 99.999992

Tags: c, struct, output

my program reads data from that file :

6 150

0 1.75

30 0.8

60 0.5

70 1

120 0.1

140 0.9

and inserts those numbers(It starts from the second row) into an array of structs and then calculates the 'time'. The results are fine but one; the third one('time') is 100 but the output is 99.999992.

Here is the program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int di,i,k,m;
float vi,time;
int n; 
int l;  

struct node 
{
    int distance;
    float velocity;

}DV[500000];

struct timeslist_node
{
    struct timeslist_node *left;
    int winner;
    int loser;
    double time;
    struct timelist_node *right;
};



double calctime(int d,float v);
void print_array();
main() 
{
    FILE *fp;


    fp=fopen("candidates.txt","r");
    if (fp==NULL) exit(2);
    fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&n,&l);
    printf("%d,%d\n",n,l);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%d %f",&DV[i].distance,&DV[i].velocity);
    }
    calctime(DV[i].distance,DV[i].velocity);
    print_array();
    fclose(fp);                   


    system("pause");
}

double calctime(int d,float v)
{      
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if (i == 0) 
        {
            {
                if (DV[n-1].velocity==DV[i].velocity)
                    time=-1;
            }

            time=((l-DV[n-1].distance)/(DV[n-1].velocity-DV[i].velocity));
            m=1;
            k=n;

        }
        else
        {

            {   if (DV[i-1].velocity==DV[i].velocity)
                time=-1;
            }
            time=((DV[i].distance-DV[i-1].distance)/(DV[i-1].velocity-DV[i].velocity));
            k=i;
            m=i+1;
        }
        printf ("t %d %d=%lf\n",m,k,time);
    }
}
void print_array()
{
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("D[%d],V[%d] = %d %.2f\n ",i,i,DV[i].distance,DV[i].velocity );
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this just boils down to the fact that `float` has limited precision.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), that's a more technical article about floating point numbers.

Comment: The program should do : (60-30)/(0.8-0.5) 

How is that even close to the limits of float?

Comment: Well, for one, because [0.80 doesn't have perfect representation in IEEE 754 floating point](http://ideone.com/uA1fnC). Read the article linked by Dirk (yes, its a long stretch, but you'll remember it quite-literally the rest of your life).

Comment: There is also a series of [blog posts by Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2005/01/10/floating-point-arithmetic-part-one.aspx) which are less mathematical than the other article I linked.

Comment: it's not because of the limit. It's because you can't represent most decimal fractional numbers in binary. There were already thousands duplicates about this on SO

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c+0.1+float  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542220/why-for-i-0-1-i-1-0-i-0-1-doesnt-break-at-i-1-0 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257166/java-floats-and-doubles-how-to-avoid-that-0-0-0-1-0-1-0-9000001?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Thats happens because floating point numbers have a limited precision. If you want to know why, have a deeper look at how floating point are stored in the memory. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point.

Comment: It's **not** because of the precision. Even if you have unlimited precision you still can't represent 0.8 in binary float correctly

Comment: @luu vinh phuc if you *had* unlimited precision, wou could represent every real number correctly. Unfortunalty, unlimited precision needs infinite size

Answer (score 0):

Typical `float` will handle math as expected, but only to within a certain range and precision.

That precision is typically about 6, maybe 7, significant digits.  See `FLT_DIG` in `<float.h>`.  `99.999992` is the results of printing a number to 8 significant digits.  Using `printf("%.5e", some_float)` will limit the output to its realistic precision.

Using `double` rather than `float` will typically provide additional range and precision.  But the same issues occur, albeit with more extreme numbers.

---

As many other have said, there are *many* issues contributing to the the fact that the sum was printed as `99.999992` rather than `100.0`.

First, the sum is most likely precisely `99.99999237060546875`, which is the previous `float`, assuming [binary32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format), to `100.0`.  Printing a number like `99.99999237060546875` to 8 significant places is moving beyond reasonable precision expectations of `float` in C.  `"%f"` prints a number with 6 digits following the decimal point.  Since the number was `99.99999237060546875`, a rounded number of `99.999992` with 2 + 6 significant digits was printed.

2nd: various math operations have inexact results.  This is expected with `1.0/3.0`, but it also happens with `100 + 0.1`.  This idea is outlined in the  classic reference *What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*

3rd, recall floating point numbers are not linearly, but logarithmically distributed.  There are about as many numbers between 1.0 and 10.0 as between 10.0 and 100.0.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! You were very helpful. Please if you have time and you want, check my other question about trees http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140517/apparently-nothing-is-inserted-into-the-tree

Answer (score -2):

Can't you use Round for this?

```
Round(*STRING*);
```

Source: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I need precision and Round takes that away.